# Растянуть содержимое div по всей странице

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, уважаемые, появилась следующая задача:
растянуть содержимое div блока на всю высоту экрана, иными словами — Если у пользователя широкий экран, то всё содержимое блока < div > растягивается по всей ширине его экрана.

Если у пользователя узкий экран, то всё содержимое блока < div > сжимается, так, чтобы не вылезать за пределы экрана.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = 'utf-8' />  
<style>
    html,body,.div {height:100%;margin:0}
    .div {background-color:#000;color:#fff;height:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = 'div' width="100%">
        <font size = '+5'>Мы работаем.</font><br />
        <image src = 'http://...' /><br />
        <font size = '+5'>Правда-правда...</font>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Приведенный мною код, к сожалению, работает неверно...
Изображение выходит за рамки экрана при этом ещё и перекрывая собою нижний текст.

Подскажите, что сделать?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Сделайте следующее:

1. **Немедленно избавьтесь от тегов** `font`, вместо них используйте `span`, `p`, `div` и т.д.
2. Стили пишите в отдельном CSS файле, или, на худой конец, в `head`.
3. В стилях для `body`, `html` пропишите:

   ```
   body, html { 
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
4. В стилях для `div`:

   ```
   .div {
       min-width: 100%;
       min-height: 100%;
       position: relative;
   }
   ```
5. В стилях для img:

   ```
   .div img {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```

Хотя, на мой взгляд, картинку лучше задать `background`'ом для `.div` и прописать для него `background-size: cover;`

Надписи так же позиционируются абсолютно.

---

P.S. А вообще, почитайте лучше по адаптивной верстке, например **[здесь](http://symby.ru/coding/adaptivnaya-vyorstka/)**. А также, и это главное, очень внимательно читайте и я бы даже сказал учите html & css - думаю, что вот [этот ресурс](http://htmlbook.ru/) Вам подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @Inkognitoo, удачи!

Answer (score 4):

С развитием нашего любимого языка *CSS*, появились величины `vw и vh`
Эти величины определяют процент от размера окна, т.е. если вы блоку укажите `100vw`, то это будет означать, что блок должен быть на всю ширину окна. Так и с `vh` - по высоте

```css
.object {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="object"></div>
```

Стоит учитывать, что оно учитывает размер вместе со скроллом и по-этому следует делать более точные расчёты :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;

    margin: 0 auto;
}
Примерно так.
```

Comment: Могу я попросить у Вас небольшой пример?

Comment: .container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1260px;
 min-width: 780px;
 
 margin: 0 auto; 
} css

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется с помощью jquery можно решить это вообще легко, к примеру так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var heightR = $(window).height();// высота экрана
var widthR = $(window).width();// ширина экрана

$('body .div').css({'width':widthR,'height':heightR}); 
});
```

Comment: $('body .div').css({'width':widthR,'height':heightR}); замените на 
$('#div').css({'width':widthR,'height':heightR});

Answer (score 1):

```
var heightR = $(window).height();// высота экрана
var widthR = $(window).width();// ширина экрана
```

Если страницы загружаются с помощью `ajax` и нужно обновление (как для чата, например), то возникают проблемы на мобильных устройствах при растяжении или увеличении... Да и вообще на `resize` экрана если что-то вешается, то проблемы неминуемы

Answer (score 0):

```
width:100%
```

Разве нет?

Comment: Мне нужно растянуть на всю _высоту_ страницы.